# Android: How do i get a launch-intent for a recent app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to get the last 7 recent apps which you can also access by longpressing your homebutton and display each of the recent apps with its icon. A click on this icon shall launch the recent app. I get the recent apps at first:

```
  ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  List<RunningTaskInfo> apps = am.getRunningTasks(7);
```

Then i gonna load the icon by getting the packageName before:

```
  final String packageName = apps.get(i).topActivity.getPackageName();
  Drawable icon = mPackageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageName);
```

In the onClick-method of my view i want to launch the recent app. My problem is to get an intent for that. I tried two different ways. 1. :

```
  final Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setPackage(packageName);
```

The code above does always create something like a chooser, but never launches a app directly. Then i tried the following code:

```
  Intent intent = mPackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
```

However, tapping on my view when using the above intent gives me the following errorlog:

```
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at com.ragingtools.launcher.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:154)
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3519)
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14140)
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
10-16 02:09:00.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 02:09:03.046: I/Process(1143): Sending signal. PID: 1143 SIG: 9
```

Please, is there any way to get the last few recent apps with an intent to launch? How can i avoid this error? Additionaly: How can i exclusively list recent apps, that are listed in the launcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getLaunchIntentForPackage` can also return a null intent if it doesnt find a main activity  in the category CATEGORY_INFO, or a main activity in the category CATEGORY_LAUNCHER. 
Do you get null in for all the packages or just one of them? If so, skip that package.